# How can I stop (Cron <root@server> run-parts /etc/cron.hourly) emails

Tags: centos, cron

I am getting these emails constantly on a new CentOS 7 server.

```
Subject: Cron <root@server> run-parts /etc/cron.hourly

/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron:

/etc/cron.hourly/50plesk-hourly:

/etc/cron.hourly/plesk-php-cleanuper:
```

I ran a repair in Plesk and it didn't find or repair anything.

I did edit crontab by changing `MAILTO=root` to `MAILTO=""`. We will see if that works.. Not a good fix because I will not see cron errors.

Here is crontab.. Is it supposed to be empty?

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=""

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

This is what I have for anacron

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Check whether 0anacron was run today already
if test -r /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily; then
    day=`cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily`
fi
if [ `date +%Y%m%d` = "$day" ]; then
    exit 0;
fi

# Do not run jobs when on battery power
if test -x /usr/bin/on_ac_power; then
    /usr/bin/on_ac_power >/dev/null 2>&1
    if test $? -eq 1; then
    exit 0
    fi
fi
/usr/sbin/anacron -s
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct, but I went into anacrontab and set `MAILTO=""`

I will make adjustments in the future. I just needed these emails to stop for now. I hope this works.

Comment: Have you tried to redirect stdout to `dev/null`? Also, this is about `run-parts`, `cron-hourly` (and `anacron` now) so the `crontab` you added into your question is expectedly empty.

Comment: I did that originally to the 3 files listed below but it has no impact.

Comment: /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron:

/etc/cron.hourly/50plesk-hourly:

/etc/cron.hourly/plesk-php-cleanuper:

Comment: There are various posts for ubuntu/centos/etc, cron/anacron, like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/175464/how-to-stop-email-report-from-cron-rootmachine-hourly Only the 2 suggestions exist, the latter for getting notifications only for errors, ok, you could further look into these posts in the near future for if you get more help, have a nice day.

Comment: I’m using cent os but thanks.